# How to return view while waiting for await function in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I work with await function for sending an email. Is there have any solutions how to display page or return view() while waiting for await function complete.

Here is my code:

```
 using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    var credential = new NetworkCredential
                    {
                        UserName = "email@gmail.com",
                        Password = "paswordEmail"
                    };
                    smtp.Credentials = credential;
                    smtp.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message); //Here is my await function for sending an email
                    return RedirectToAction("ThankYou"); //This thank you page. I want to display this html page without waiting for await complete
                }
```

Comment: Simply just don't await the send.

Comment: If not going to await the send then remove it from the using block else it may go out of scope before it has time to complete.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins its error if remove await - 
[InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]

Comment: If you need to await then wrap it inside of a Task.Run(()=> {});

Comment: You can also just call send inside of Task.Run(()=> {}) or use the Async Nkosi posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the mail code in a `Task.Run` and not await it.

```
Task.Run(async () => {
    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()) {
        var credential = new NetworkCredential {
            UserName = "email@gmail.com",
            Password = "paswordEmail"
        };
        smtp.Credentials = credential;
        smtp.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message); //Here is my await function for sending an email
    }
});
return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
```

Comment: But you shouldn't. You can take down the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has it's own facility to execute background work: [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem).

Just post your work there:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(
    async () =>
    {
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "email@gmail.com",
                    Password = "paswordEmail",
                },
            })
        {
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(message); //Here is my await function for sending an email
        }
    });
return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
```